# 'TimeZoneInfo' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertTimeFromUtc' (DNX Core 5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

The code below used to work fine before upgrading to asp5. The method **ConvertTimeFromUtc** is not supported by DNX Core 5.0. Is there another proper way of achieving this?

```
public DateTime GmtNow() {
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"));
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"))`?

Comment: Oh, so it's been refactored then, makes sense. Thanks. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Cheers

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but what exactly is the point of this conversion? Doesn't `DateTime.UtcNow` already give you the correct value? Yes, `DateTime.UtcNow` doesn't ever have any daylight savings time, but GMT isn't supposed to have that either, even if Microsoft does confusingly claim it does.

Comment: Well, there's a few variables that I need to account for. I have an Irish website, but the server is hosted in Netherlands and I want to return the Irish time for all users. Also, when using plain utc I noticed daylight savings issues, so a proper conversion needs to be made, which is why I needed the solution above. Hope it makes sense, thanks for asking.

Comment: Also, it is just a terminology confusion. Microsoft uses GMT to refer to the timezone containing Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London and those do use daylight savings. Also, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").SupportsDaylightSavingTime will return true, so daylight savings are supported.

Comment: @Toonsylvania Thanks for explaining. You may want to avoid copying Microsoft's mistake and rename your method from `GmtNow()` to something that more accurately reflects what you're trying to return, but even if you don't, your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That method doesn't exist any more, I assume it's because the following method covers all options:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
    DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"))
```

Comment: How is this different than DateTime.UtcNow ? GMT doesn't have DST so the result will always be the same

Comment: It is just a terminology confusion. Microsoft uses GMT to refer to the timezone containing Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London and those do use daylight savings. Try this: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").SupportsDaylightSavingTime. It outputs true.

Comment: @Toonsylvania : Hi, `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` method returns bool, so how would we get converted datetime for such timezones which support day-light savings. I am facing an issue with for one conversion from GMT to `Eastern Standard Timezone`. And the same datetime conversion for GMT to `Mountain Standard Timezone` works correctly. Is there any specific to TimeZone areas?